# Obtener dato de un metodo Override

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webservice

Deseo obtener un valor cualquiera de un método Override que se encuentra dentro de otro método para poder retornar un dato y poder realizar una comparación.

Dentro del metodo `onResponse` deseo obtener un dato para que el metodo `cargarDatos` pueda retornar un valor y realizar una comparación para ejecutar una acción:

```
 public void cargarDatos(final String est){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url="";
    StringRequest js=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.equals("[]")){
                SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                String fec=fmt.format(new Date());
                grabarMal(cod_per,cod_tra,fec,est);
                android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(usuVerDatos.this);
                builder.setMessage("Inspector "+nom+" el código escaneado en "+tra+" no se encuentra registrado").setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent a=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),usuPrincipal.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                        .setCancelable(false).show();

            }else {
                try {
                    JSONArray json=new JSONArray(response);

                  Estivador a=new Estivador(json.getJSONObject(0).getString("cod_est"),json.getJSONObject(0).getString("nom_est"),
                            json.getJSONObject(0).getString("ape_pat_est"),json.getJSONObject(0).getString("ape_mat_est"),
                            json.getJSONObject(0).getString("dni_est"), json.getJSONObject(0).getString("nom_aso"),json.getJSONObject(0).getString("fot_est"),json.getJSONObject(0).getString("cod_aso"));

                    String url="";


                    txtEstCodDatos.setText(a.getCod_est().toString());
                    txtEstNomDatos.setText(a.getNom_est().toString());
                    txtEstApePatDatos.setText(a.getApe_pat_est().toString());
                    txtEstApeMatDatos.setText(a.getApe_mat_est().toString());
                    txtEstDniDatos.setText(a.getDni_est().toString());
                    txtEstAsoDatos.setText(a.getNom_aso().toString());
                    cargarimagen(url+a.getFot_est().toString());

                    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                    String fec=fmt.format(new Date());
                    grabarCorrecto(cod_per,cod_tra,a.getCod_est().toString(),a.getCod_aso().toString(),fec);


                }catch (JSONException e){

                }
            }}
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(usuVerDatos.this,"Error en la conexión",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(js);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta creando un listener que se ejecute cuando obtengas las respuesta del servidor. Esto porque si quieres retornar la respuesta del servidor, tendras que hacer el request sincronico lo que a su vez te forzara crear un `Task` para evitar utilizar controles de la vista en otro hilo.

Crea una interfaz:

```
public interface DatosResponseListener
{
  void datosResponse(String datos);
}
```

Entonces en tu metodo le defines el listener que lo ejecutaras cuando obtengas el resultado:

```
public void cargarDatos(final String est, DatosResponseListener listener)
{
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url="";
    StringRequest js=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
         listener.datosResponse(response);
          //..
```

Entonces el uso seria:

```
cargarDatos("est", new DatosResponseListener(){
  @Override
  public void datosResponse(String response)
  {
     // procesas la respuesta del servidor
  }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. El código me funciona de manera correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Declara una variable en el metodo `cargarDatos` a la que le asignes el valor que quieres en el metodo `onResponse`, luego retornas esa variable.

```
public String cargarDatos(final String est){

    // variable en la que almacenaras el valor que quieres obtener de onResponse
    String obtenerValor = "";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url="";
    StringRequest js=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            // Aqui le asignas el valor que quieres a la variable.
            obtenerValor = response;

            if(response.equals("[]")){
                SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                String fec=fmt.format(new Date());
                grabarMal(cod_per,cod_tra,fec,est);
                android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(usuVerDatos.this);
                builder.setMessage("Inspector "+nom+" el código escaneado en "+tra+" no se encuentra registrado").setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                         Intent a=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),usuPrincipal.class);
                         startActivity(a);
                         finish();
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false).show();

            }else {
                try {
                    JSONArray json=new JSONArray(response);

                  Estivador a=new Estivador(json.getJSONObject(0).getString("cod_est"),json.getJSONObject(0).getString("nom_est"),
                        json.getJSONObject(0).getString("ape_pat_est"),json.getJSONObject(0).getString("ape_mat_est"),
                        json.getJSONObject(0).getString("dni_est"), json.getJSONObject(0).getString("nom_aso"),json.getJSONObject(0).getString("fot_est"),json.getJSONObject(0).getString("cod_aso"));

                    String url="";


                    txtEstCodDatos.setText(a.getCod_est().toString());
                    txtEstNomDatos.setText(a.getNom_est().toString());
                    txtEstApePatDatos.setText(a.getApe_pat_est().toString());
                    txtEstApeMatDatos.setText(a.getApe_mat_est().toString());
                    txtEstDniDatos.setText(a.getDni_est().toString());
                    txtEstAsoDatos.setText(a.getNom_aso().toString());
                    cargarimagen(url+a.getFot_est().toString());

                    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                    String fec=fmt.format(new Date());
                    grabarCorrecto(cod_per,cod_tra,a.getCod_est().toString(),a.getCod_aso().toString(),fec);


                }catch (JSONException e){

                }
            }}
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(usuVerDatos.this,"Error en la conexión",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    queue.add(js);

    // retornas el valor que le asignaste a la variable 
    return obtenerValor;

}
```